What’s with all the random [compiler-construction] tags?
I am curious. I see a lot of old posts being edited where the major change is removal of the compiler-construction tag.
As yet, not one of those old posts has anything to do with compiler construction.
Am I missing something? (What’s the story?)

that tag has some history

If a user is removing [tag:compiler-construction] from lots of old posts, doesn't one expect that those posts are significantly more likely not to relate to compiler construction?

@francescalus Clearly. The question is why users would ever tag their post with compiler-construction to begin with.

Ah, that would almost certainly be because of (as Kevin B hints at above) the synonym that was there until a month ago.

@KevinB Ah, so, if user tagged “compiler” it automagically turned into “compiler-construction”? Seems odd to me that “compilers” is also a synonym for it. Compiler-construction/design is a very specific field...

That's correct.  Regarding the "compilers" synonym, my general impression is that "compilers" is generally used to refer to that field, but... I could be wrong and maybe people will continue to misuse it.  I'm open to removing that one also if it continues to be a problem.

@RyanM Heh, I have learned that no matter how clean-cut a piece of language is, people will misuse it. Alas. So, it all makes better sense now... Though I still think it weird that people over-tag a programming post with “compiler”. Lol.

People also frequently tag the editor they were using when they saw the error, so...yeah, this doesn't surprise me, but maybe I'm just jaded :)

Worse still are the people who only tag the editor ... as if it is (say) an Eclipse problem that they don't understand (say) basic Java.  (Maybe, we'd be better off if tagging was left to an AI. :-) )

@StephenC For sure the algorithms will be much better at doing it all wrong, human beings will still sometimes try to do the right thing. Automated chaos ftw.

@Gimby - At least an AI can be trained.  That doesn't work with new users.  (Well eventually user training works, but it takes too long and causes too much aggravation.)  And the flip side is that an AI is not going to be offended when you tell it that it has tagged a question incorrectly.

I'm pretty confident that a properly trained AI could tag questions more accurately than a newbie user.  And it is less risky than getting the AI to answer question.  (In terms of the consequences ...)
